# Need help creating iphone app

Tags: ios, software-design

This is what I want to do:
Use 2 picker views that you can choose from.
Person then clicks on button to do process from what the user chosed.
The two arguments are used from the pickers and then data is displayed on the bottom.

I know C++ and created a ddos version of this using a menu style but I'm very new to objective-C and iphone development. I just need help tieing the objects together. The first picker will be used as an argument and the 2nd will be used as a switch with the variable and calculate something when the button is pushed onto the display at the bottom. I know this is a huge request but would love if somebody could point me in right direction.

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    int maxRow = [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    int programRow = [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];

    NSLog(@"One Rep Max Chosen: %@", [oneRepMax objectAtIndex:maxRow];
    NSLog(@"Program Chosen: %@", [program objectAtIndex:programRow];

    NSString *allInformation = [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@%@\n%@", [oneRepMax objectAtIndex:maxRow],[program objectAtIndex:programRow]];

    int level = programRow;
    int max = [[oneRepMax objectAtIndex:maxRow]intValue];
    int set1;
    int set2;
    int set3;
    int set4;

    switch(level)
    {
        case 0:
        {
             set1 = max * 0.7;
             set2 = max * 0.71;
             set3 = max * 0.72;
             set4 = max * 0.73;
             break;
        }
        case1:
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, short answer is get a book because I don't know how much you know about Objective C :D

But this seems like a straight forward question, I can offer some general ideas of one way to go about it.

I'm going to use pure coding rather than Interface Builder but I would recommend using Interface Builder as it separates interface setups from actual code logic.

This code assumes **Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)** is used

### ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The UIPickerViewDelegate is a protocol (kinda of like an abstract class in C++)
// you need to implement the methods (or functions in C++ terms) of the protocol
//
// The UIPickerViewDataSource also a protocol to tell your ViewController to expect
// a method that provides your UIPickerViews the data it needs to display.
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
    // UIPickerView can have multiple components (multiple roller thing)
    UIPickerView *myPicker;

    // arrays to hold your data
    NSArray *list1;
    NSArray *list2;

    // our button to do something when pressed
    UIButton *btnCalculate;
}

@end
```

### ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    myPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // these two lines are compulsory, it is saying the picker view's
    // delegate and datasource is this view controller itself
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    myPicker.delegate = self;
    myPicker.dataSource = self;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Here we're specifying what we want to show in each row of the
    // picker view. Each of these array will be loaded into each of
    // the picker view components (see below)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // -------------------------------------
    // |    apple        |     option 1    |
    // |    banana       |     option 2    |
    // |    orange       |     option 3    |
    // |    mango        |                 |
    // |    peach        |                 |
    // -------------------------------------

    list1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple", @"banana", @"orange", @"mango", @"peach", nil];
    list2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"option1", @"option2", @"option3", nil];


    btnCalculate = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 300, 100, 50)];
    btnCalculate.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [btnCalculate setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCalculate setTitle:@"Calculate" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // this is how we add a callback method for the button tap event
    [btnCalculate addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:myPicker];
    [self.view addSubview:btnCalculate];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Your UIPickerViewDataSource methods you need to implement
// ------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    // we're telling the our picker we want 2 rollers in a single picker view
    // like this:

    // -------------------------------------
    // |                 |                 |
    // |                 |                 |
    // |   component 1   |   component 2   |
    // |                 |                 |
    // |                 |                 |
    // -------------------------------------

    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // this is telling the picker how many rows to expect for each picker
    // it must match up with our data source (which in this case is our
    // list1 and list2).
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // -------------------------------------
    // |                 |                 |
    // |                 |                 |
    // |     5 fruits    |     3 options   |
    // |                 |                 |
    // |                 |                 |
    // -------------------------------------

    if(component == 0)
    {
        return list1.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return list2.count;
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Your UIPickerViewDelegate methods you need to implement
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// This method will return the actual text into the picker view
// components.
//
// Note: This is for basic UIPickerView, if you want more fancy
// looking rows, you need to implement the other delegate method
// instead of this one.
// ------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
    {
        return [list1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        return [list2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Your callback method for when user taps on your button
// ------------------------------------------------------------
-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    int fruitRow = [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    int optionRow = [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];

    // This will print the result into Xcode's console window
    NSLog(@"Fruit chosen: %@", [list1 objectAtIndex:fruitRow]);
    NSLog(@"Option chosen: %@", [list2 objectAtIndex:optionRow]);

    // This will show a popup alert view with same information
    NSString *allInformation = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",
                                [list1 objectAtIndex:fruitRow], [list2 objectAtIndex:optionRow]];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information"
                                                    message:allInformation
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}


@end
```

### Final Result

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

From there you modify the method `-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender` to do whatever you like.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What I'm trying to do is you pick a one rep max in the first column. The second column you pick the sets and how many reps. How can I use the value from the first and use multiplication and other things and store it and then print it off like Sets: Set 1: 300x10
Set 2: 325x10
Set 3: 350x10

Inside the buttonTapped I created a switch(level) that uses the value from the row called in the 2nd column. It will then go to the case and I want to take the value from the first column and multiply it and put to the screen multiple sets.

Comment: Uh, sorry I don't quite understand your question. If a string value is pure numbers e.g. a string "300", you can convert that string to a number using [[list1 objectAtIndexRow:fruitRow] intValue].

Comment: I was able to get ahold of using the UIAlertView. The question is how do you round up a number such as 3 to 5 or 8 to 10? Also how would I format those answers into a table view instead of a UIAlertView?

Comment: As I said in the answer, you modify the buttonTapped method to do whatever you want. I only use an alert view as an example. As for rounding numbers, do another Stackoverflow search, I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: How do you create multiple pickers such as a tabbed application and using a picker on two of the views?